# Why xor equation is true?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Why is

$$(a \oplus b)+(b \oplus c) \geq (a \oplus c)$$

true for any non-negative integers $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Also $\oplus$ works on binary string [more details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)

Comment: If a and c have the same parity then it is clear as the right hand side is 0. If a and c have different parity then whatever the parity of b, one of the term on the left is 1 and the other is 0 which gives you the equality.

Comment: What is the meaning of the title "Approve xor equation"?  Specifically, "approve" what?

Comment: You question is not clear.

Comment: Why overcomplicate things by letting $a,b,c$ be non-negative integers?  Isn't $a,b,c\in\{0,1\}$ sufficient and equivalent?

Comment: @mjw Sorry, i've mixed up math and cs rules. In programming a xor b means en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or (translate a and b from deciminal to binary and do operations on 0 and 1 numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only chance for this to be false, is if the right hand side equals $1$ and the left hand side equals zero.  Well, if the right hand side is $1$, either $a$ or $c$ is non-zero, but not both.  So $a\ne c$.  Then, since $b$ is either $0$ or non-zero, one of the terms on the left hand side is equal to $1$, so the statement is true and always true.

**UPDATE**

Since it has been made clear "why integers," just convert to binary and this argument works bitwise, and thus for all $a,b,c$ binary.